# PostgreSQL: Return value with case if text is found in varchar array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, case, varchar

Imagine the data:

```
id       item        category                         basket
1        Banana      {"Fruit"}                        {"Veggie","Health"}
2        Carrot      {"Veggie"}                       {"Health","Beauty","Art"}
3        Banana      {"Fruit","Health"}               {"Beauty","Art","Veggie","Health"}
4        Potato      {"Beauty","Veggie","Art"}        {"Beauty","Veggie"}
5        Lipstick    {"Fruit"}                        {"Veggie", "Health", "Beauty"}
```

I would like to obtain:

```
id       item        category                         basket                                include_item
1        Banana      {"Fruit"}                        {"Veggie","Health"}                   add_fruit
2        Carrot      {"Veggie"}                       {"Health","Beauty","Art"}             add_veggie
3        Banana      {"Fruit","Health"}               {"Beauty","Art","Veggie","Health"}    add_fruit
4        Potato      {"Beauty","Veggie","Art"}        {"Beauty","Veggie"}                   add_veggie
5        Lipstick    {"Fruit"}                        {"Veggie", "Health", "Beauty"}        do_not_add
```

I attempted the code:

```
select *,
     case
         -- when category::char like '%Fruit%' and item = 'Banana' then 'add_fruit'
         -- when 'Vegetable'=any(category) and item in ('Potato', 'Carrot') then 'add_veggie'
         else 'do_not_add'
     end as include_item
from my_table
```

Neither of the commented options worked. How should I adjust the code to meet both criteria in `case` ?

Both `category` and `basket` are of type `character varying[]`

Comment: In what way did it "not work"?  *("It didn't work", without any descriptions, is the least helpful phrase ever used in questions here.)*  The `LIKE` expression should have worked?  Also, why is the data in a string, not a native array or a JSON format?  Do you have the option to Fix the datatype being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could normalize your table, so that you don't need to make string comparisons.

> ```
> select *,
>      case
>          when category like '%Fruit%' and item = 'Banana' then 'add_fruit'
>          when category like '%Veggie%' and item in ('Potato', 'Carrot') then 'add_veggie'
>          else 'do_not_add'
>      end as include_item
> from ordertab
> ```
>
> ```
> id | item     | category                  | basket                             | include_item
> -: | :------- | :------------------------ | :--------------------------------- | :-----------
>  1 | Banana   | {"Fruit"}                 | {"Veggie","Health"}                | add_fruit   
>  2 | Carrot   | {"Veggie"}                | {"Health","Beauty","Art"}          | add_veggie  
>  3 | Banana   | {"Fruit","Health"}        | {"Beauty","Art","Veggie","Health"} | add_fruit   
>  4 | Potato   | {"Beauty","Veggie","Art"} | {"Beauty","Veggie"}                | add_veggie  
>  5 | Lipstick | {"Fruit"}                 | {"Veggie", "Health", "Beauty"}     | do_not_add
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4919aba2cee7dfe8103913627c18847f)*